# sharepoint sent email attachment don't having pdf format

Tags: development, email, pdf

code is developed to attach pdf and send as email. 
But email received dont contain the pdf format. On click of file, it gives option of "open with".
mentioned is code used....
"attach1" is the path of the pdf which is in library.
string email = string.Empty; 
string smtpServer =SPAdministrationWebApplication.Local.OutboundMailServiceInstance.Server.Address;
string smtpFrom = SPAdministrationWebApplication.Local.OutboundMailSenderAddress;
MemoryStream memoryStreamOfFile1 = null;

data1 = webClient.DownloadData(attach1);
memoryStreamOfFile1 = new MemoryStream(data1);
mail.Attachments.Add(new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(memoryStreamOfFile1, empID,"application/pdf"));
smtpClient.Send(mail);

Answer (score 0):

Plz try below code..

```
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
smtpClient.Host = SPContext.Current.Site.WebApplication.OutboundMailServiceInstance.Server.Address;
string fromAddress = SPContext.Current.Site.WebApplication.OutboundMailReplyToAddress;
List<Attachment> attachments = new List<Attachment>();
string mimeType = "application/pdf";
System.IO.Stream stream = yourpdfSPFileObject.OpenBinaryStream();
Attachment attach = new Attachment(stream, mimeType);
attach.Name = file.Name;
attachments.Add(attach);
MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage(fromAddress, emailAddress, Subject, Body);

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Cc))
                {
                    MailAddress CCAddress = new MailAddress(Cc);
                    mailMessage.CC.Add(CCAddress);
                }
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Bcc))
                {
                    MailAddress BCCAddress = new MailAddress(Bcc);
                    mailMessage.Bcc.Add(BCCAddress);
                }
                if (attachments.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (Attachment attachment in attachments)
                    {
                        mailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachment);
                    }
                }
                mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = IsBodyHtml;
                smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
```

Hope it helps..